# Entire relation, projective object and choice object, and the axiom of choice

Tags: category-theory, axiom-of-choice, topos-theory

I was reading on the axiom of choice and I came across these few statements in nLab:

1. Projective object: $P$ is projective if for any morphism $f: P \rightarrow B$ and any epimorphism $q: A \rightarrow B$, $f$ factors through $q$ by some morphism $P \rightarrow A$.
2. The axiom of choice can be phrased as "all objects of the category of sets are projective".
3. Entire relation: A binary relation from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ is called entire if every element $X$ is related to at least one element of $Y$.
4. The axiom of choice says precisely that every entire relation contains a function.
5. A set $A$ is projective iff every entire relation from $A$ to set $B$, for any $B$, contains a function $A \rightarrow B$.
6. A set $B$ is choice iff every entire relation from a set $A$ to $B$, for any $A$, contains a function $A \rightarrow B$.

Statement 1, 2: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/projective+object

Statement 3, 4: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/entire+relation

Statement 5, 6: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/choice+object

My question is, how are the statements related. That is, how is (1) and (5) related, how is (2) and (4) related, and how does (6) sit in this whole picture (is there any significance of this statement)?

Comment: Do not cross post. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362637/entire-relation-projective-object-and-choice-object-and-the-axiom-of-choice

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps lets start with the relations between surjections, entire relations, and indexed families of nonempty sets.

It turns out these three notions are equivalent.

Suppose $f:A\to B$ is a surjection. Define a relation $R:B\to A$ by $bRa\iff f(a)=b$. Since $f$ is surjective, this relation is entire. On the other hand, if $b\in B$, define $A_b = f^{-1}(\{b\})$, since $f$ is a surjection, each $A_b$ is nonempty, so we have a family of (disjoint) nonempty sets indexed by $B$.

Now suppose we have an entire relation $R:B\to A$. Define $A_b = \{a\in A: bRa\}$, which gives a family of nonempty sets indexed by $B$, since $R$ is entire. Finally, define $$A'=\bigsqcup_{b\in B} A_b,$$
and $f:A'\to B$ by $f(a,b)=b$.

Lastly, suppose we start with a family of nonempty sets indexed by $B$, $A_b$. Then again, we define $A'=\bigsqcup_{b\in B} A_b$, and $f:A'\to B$ by $f(a,b)=b$, which is surjective, since all the $A_b$ are nonempty. On the other hand, we can define an entire relation $R:B\to A'$ by $b R (a,b)$. (Or we could take $A=\bigcup_{b\in B} A_b$ and $R:B\to A$ by $bRa \iff a\in A_b$.)

**Choice**

One version of the axiom of choice says that if $A_b$ is a family of nonempty sets indexed by $B$, then there is a function 
$$g:B\to A'= \bigsqcup_{b\in B} A_b$$
such that $fg=1_B$, where $f:A'\to B$ is the surjective function constructed above.
$g$ is called a *choice function*.

Now the relationship between the statements of choice in the question is the following:

> The following are equivalent
>    1. Choice (as stated just now)
>    2. Every surjective function has a right inverse.
>    3. Every set is projective
>    4. Every entire relation contains a function

*Proof*

(1) $\implies$ (2): Given a surjective function $f:A\to B$, and applying choice to the family of sets $A_b=f^{-1}(b)$, we get a function $g:B\to A$ such that $fg =1_B$.

(2) $\implies$ (3): Suppose $f:A\to B$ is surjective, and $h:X\to B$ is any map of sets.
To show that all sets are projective, it suffices to show that we can always lift $h$ to a map $\tilde{h}:X\to A$. However, if $g:B\to A$ is a left inverse, then we can take $\tilde{h}= gh$, since then $f\tilde{h}=fgh=h$.

(3) $\implies$ (1): Suppose $A_b$ is a family of nonempty sets. Then $f : A'\to B$ is surjective, and $B$ is projective, so we can lift $1_B$ along $f$ to a map $g:B\to A'$ such that $fg=1_B$, which is the statement of choice.

(4) $\implies$ (2): If $f:A\to B$ is surjective, and $R:B\to A$ is the entire relation constructed above, and $g:B\to A$ is a function contained in $R$, then by definition, 
$bRg(b)$, which means that $fg(b)=b$, so $g$ is a right inverse to $f$.

(1) $\implies$ (4): If $R : B\to A$ is an entire relation, then we defined a family of nonempty subsets $A_b=\{a\in A: bRa\}$. Letting $\tilde{g}:B\to A'$ be a choice function for this family, we have $\tilde{g}(b) = (a,b)$ for some $a$ with $bRa$, and we define $g:B\to A$ by $g(b)=a$, which gives a function contained in $R$.
$\blacksquare$

**The relations of the statements in your question**

(1) is the definition of projective, which is used in statement (5).

I just showed (2) and (4) are equivalent to choice.

(6) is equivalent to saying that any family of nonempty sets indexed by $B$ has a choice function, so it's choice for sets indexed by that set.

Comment: I guess it is possible to write the axiom of choice in terms of choice object?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, it would be that every set is a choice object.

Comment: Would the empty set cause a problem?

Comment: More specifically, is the empty set a projective object and/or a choice object? I think that the empty set is a projective object and not a choice object because of the definition of entire relation. If what I think is right, then not every set is a choice object. Hm... but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Jerry The empty set is projective, since it is initial, so we can always lift any morphism out of the empty set along any other morphism (surjective or not). It is also a choice object. If you have an entire relation from $A$ to $\varnothing$, then every element of $a$ must be related to at least one element of $\varnothing$, and since $\varnothing$ has no elements, this means $A$ can't have any elements either, so $A=\varnothing$ as well, and the relation is actually already the unique function $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, so it does contain a function.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I should interpret "for any $A$" in statement (6) as "for any $A$, conditioned on $A \rightarrow B$ is a entire relation, ..." Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you might want to read it as: For any $A$ *which admits an entire relation to $B$*.

Comment: Thanks!! That helps a lot :)

Comment: A final clarification. In https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice, it says that: an object $A$ such that one can make choices ‘with values in’ $A$ is called a choice object (this is not quite equivalent to every epimorphism $A\rightarrow B$ splitting). Do you know what the sentence in the brackets means? What does it mean that this is not quite equivalent?

Comment: @Jerry, I'll have to take a look at that later. I was focusing on the category of sets, and things might stop being equivalent in a different category, so I'll take a look at that later.